# Are linear continuous mappings open on totally bounded sets?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be locally convex spaces, and $\varphi: X\to Y$ a linear continuous mapping. Suppose first that $S$ is a compact set in $X$. Then $\varphi$, being considered as a mapping from $S$ to $\varphi(S)$,
$$
\varphi\Big|_S:S\to \varphi(S)
$$
is *open* in the sense that for any open set $U$ in $S$ (with respect to the topology induced from $X$) its image $\varphi(U)$ is an open set in $\varphi(S)$ (with respect to the topology induced from $Y$).

This is strange, I was sure that the same must be true if $S$ is not necessarily compact, but just totally bounded (since we can consider the extension of $\varphi$ to the completions of the spaces $X$ and $Y$), but recently I understood unexpectedly that I can't write an accurate proof. Does this mean that there is a counterexample?

So my question:

> Is $\varphi\Big|_S:S\to \varphi(S)$ an open mapping for each totally bounded set $S$ in $X$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bounded sets, e.g., unit balls in normed spaces, are always totally bounded for weak topologies. So you only have to find such a ball with two incompatible weak topologies, which is easy to do—say the ball of a suitable dual space with the weak and the weak $\ast$ topology.

Comment: Thank you! I was stuck in this, you helped me!